# Integrate BitBucket Private Repository with Gitbook Private Book

Tags: gitbook, bitbucket-cloud

I want to integrate my private bitbucket repository with gitbook private book.

Anyone could suggest a way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1:
You can first create a repository in Bitbucket. Once you have that done you need to check the "Get started with command line",  if you have to initialize a new project or you would like to use your existing project. Keep the commands from that handy because for the next step you would be using it.

Step 2 :
Now you have to go to the gitbook directory. In Linux it is normally at 
`/home/<username>/GitBook/Library/Import`. In this directory go into the book which you would like to push to bitbucket. (Please check for Windows)

Run the commands from Step 1. Your Bitbucket repo should be populated.